# How to have a hierarchy of hibernate objects to load all the lazy associations?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have a deep hierarchy of beans, with many lazy associations. What if I want them to load all these associations (with going object by object and trying to access every association so that it triggers queries)?